# Why are there so many unexpected shutdowns in the event log?

Tags: windows-8.1, shutdown, event-log

I was looking through my shutdown history in the event log today when I noticed that there was an "Unexpected Shutdown" (event ID 6008) logged way more often than I can ever recall there being unexpected shutdowns.

[image: Event log screenshot.]

I do know that every so often I have to hold the power button down to shut off the computer because it gets stuck in the "Shutting down" screen, but that only happens once in a blue moon. Maybe once a month at the very most. If I were to believe these logs, it'd happen once a week and sometimes almost every other day.

And to add to the confusion, despite the fact that these events have been logged about once a week or more since I bought the computer a year ago, they haven't been logged again since almost 2 months ago. From what I can see, this is the only time there's been a gap that large between the events. I always use the shut down option in the UI whenever I can. Running "sfc /scannow" today in the admin command line has found no integrity violations (though it has found some every so often in the past).

Why is this happening? Is there anything to worry about here or is it just a bug? Is there anything else I can do to be sure that there's nothing up with my PC?

Comment: look at the details: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2028504/en-us

Comment: Event ID 41 happens about as often as 6008, though the last log date entry is 2015-09-17. The details tab always lists the BugCheckCode and BugCheckParameters as 0s. SleepInProgress varies between 0 and 6. PowerButtonTimestamp is almost always 0 but the last four times it was a huge number value. BootAppStatus seems to always be 3221225684. Looking through the scenarios on that page, like I said, I do occassionally hold the power button down because my computer stays on the shutting down screen, but not nearly this often. There haven't been power outages or anything lately either.

Comment: Any shutdown that did not cleanly shutdown can trigger this event code, even when you tell it to shutdown or restart normally if all does not go well it will set this event.

Comment: turn the new fast boot off and look if Windows now shuts down correctly: http://www.eightforums.com/tutorials/6320-fast-startup-turn-off-windows-8-a.html

Comment: @magicandre1981 You're right, fast boot was probably it! Turned it off about a month or two ago and that coincides around when event ID 41 and 6008 stopped being logged in event viewer. Still weird that 6008 and 41 didn't stop at the same time (as I'd assume that they'd coincide) but I think fast boot was the culprit. Hopefully no damage was done to my computer due to it not shutting down cleanly for over a year. This is weird, as this is a prebuilt that came with Windows 8, so fast boot definitely _should_ have worked properly, but evidently not. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I do know that every so often I have to hold the power button down to shut off the computer because it gets stuck in the "Shutting down" screen

Because Windows uses a new boot way called [fast startup mode](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/b8/archive/2011/09/08/delivering-fast-boot-times-in-windows-8.aspx), which is doing a logoff of the user and now hibernates the kernel. During boot it resume the kernel and brings you so faster to the logon screen.

But hibernation can sometimes cause issues (drivers or BIOS problems) and it looks like it doesn't work for you correctly.

[Turn it off in the control panel.](http://www.eightforums.com/tutorials/6320-fast-startup-turn-off-windows-8-a.html)

[image]

and now Windows uses the old way to fully shutdown and this should fix your issue.

Comment: Thank you! Also solved my "every other boot would fail to work in Windows 10" issue over in [this thread](http://superuser.com/questions/1113484/windows-10-crashing-every-other-startup-sleep-seems-to-fully-shut-down-too/1113915).