# Windows 10 Crashing Every Other Startup; Sleep seems to fully shut down too

Tags: windows-10, boot, crash

Within the last month or so, my PC has been basically crashing on startup every other boot. It never wavers: First time from a cold start, it starts loading Windows 10, then stops. When I reset via the PC case's reset button, it starts normal. Next time I shut down (or even put it to Sleep mode), the process repeats.

The failure seems to happen in one of two ways. I took a series of small videos (apologies if the video plays sideways):

- First attempt to boot up [results in no spinner on the Windows 10 load screen](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/15545173/temp/PC%20Fail%20Boot/01%20Fail%20-%20No%20Spinner.mp4). Hangs forever.
- Next attempt it [boots up normally](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/15545173/temp/PC%20Fail%20Boot/02%20Success.mp4)
- Next attempt the spinner [seems to crash, and the screen fades to black](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/15545173/temp/PC%20Fail%20Boot/03%20Fail%20-%20Spinner%20Crash.mp4). Hangs forever.
- Next attempt it boots up normally again (no video here).

Like clockwork it is every other boot that fails to start. And as mentioned above, if I even put the computer to sleep (which I normally never do, but for testing this out I've been trying), on wake up it seems to go through the same process as a cold start.

#### What it is not

- Windows 10 Anniversary Update: This problem predates the installation of the Windows 10 Anniversary update/edition on my PC.
- Peripheral hardware (except the monitor I guess): Tried booting with nothing plugged in except the monitors shown in the above video.

#### What might've caused it

- I had Catalyst Control Center installed for years now. I don't know when, but at some point (when I started digging) it enabled some Adaptive Sleep Service, which kept changing my Power Options to things like "make the hard disk shut off after 3 minutes of inactivity" and other such nonsense. I only started digging when this problem first started to occur.

  - Eventually I just uninstalled CCC altogether and manually disabled the service that kept resetting my power options. Currently my Power Options are back at what they were: Turn off the display after 1 hour, and that's it. No other auto-power options are enabled.

#### PC Details

- [Winver](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/15545173/temp/PC%20Fail%20Boot/winver.png) (Windows 10 Pro; Version 1607, OS Build 14393.51)
- 16 GB RAM
- [CPU](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/15545173/temp/PC%20Fail%20Boot/CPU-Z/CPU.png)
- [Graphics](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/15545173/temp/PC%20Fail%20Boot/CPU-Z/Graphics.png)
- Any additional information available upon request.

Comment: I do not have an answer. But I can suggest you make a "Reset PC". Last day I got the Anniversary Update, and my computer was slow at any task. I had made the upgrade to Windows 10 from a Windows 7 that I had working for years. So I chose the "Reset PC" option, that keeps user files, but reinstalls the OS. I had to reinstall all programs, but this is not a big deal, an hour work. Now my Windows 10 (1607, build 14393.51) works perfectly well. So, you could always move to this last resort - "Reset PC" with keeping user files.

Comment: Yeah, that's a solution I'm keeping in my back pocket for now. I've been running Windows 10 for months now, without issue. Only recently did this start becoming a thing. That's kind of a last resort option for me, though I realize that might be the only option I have.

Comment: Had a similar problem when upgraded from Win 7 to Win 10. My  netbook-Asus 1215N. After I upgraded to Win10, every time I did a cold start, it reached to the Windows logo with several spinning dots, then a slight creaky sound like from the HDD, and stopped to a full Power Off.
If I press again the Power button, it then started absolutely normally.
As in your case, this was every second time from a cold start.
I had used BCDedit before, I thought it is the problem.
Now, after "Reset PC", I do NOT have the problem! I see a new-made BottSect file. http://vi8.info/pic/2016-08/Changed-Boot.jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it. Curious, I checked the Event Log, and found out that Windows was actually apparently having issue recovering from an apparently-botched shutdown. In time to when I turn the computer off and on, I would get

`Event ID 41 - The system has rebooted without cleanly shutting down first. This error could be caused if the system stopped responding, crashed, or lost power unexpectedly.`

And then after that (by the timestamp when I would reset the PC to start again):

`Event ID 6008 - The previous system shutdown at <time> on <date> was unexpected.`

Googling that eventually led me to [this Super User answer](https://superuser.com/a/985372/121722). Indeed, Windows' somewhat-recent "Fast Startup" feature was the thing doing it. At a guess, Windows is not able to successfully do the hybrid functionality on my machine, and every subsequent boot from that state never worked. A reset then forces it to truly start from scratch, and that always works.

Just did a reboot and started up normal!

FYI, the answer posts an out of date screenshot. In Windows 10, open up Power Options in Control Panel, then click "Choose what the power buttons do." For whatever reason, this is where the "Shutdown settings" are now located. Clicking "Change settings that are currently unavailable" will let you check/uncheck those boxes.

[image: Shutdown Settings location]